# Share links via Facebook Messenger - react-native android

Tags: facebook, react-native, facebook-share, react-native-fbsdk

I want to share links only via `Facebook` messenger. I have checked 3 libraries and none of them has what I need:

1. `Share` (build-in in react-native): not possible to share links in Android
2. `react-native-share`: doesn't support sharing via FB messenger, only via Facebook
3. `react-native-fbsdk`: not possible to share via messenger, only via Facebook

How is possible to implement this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution in react-native-fbsdk, there is possibility to share links via Fb messenger using `MessageDialog`.

```
shareLinkWithShareDialog= () => {
    var tmp = this;
    MessageDialog.canShow(this.state.shareLinkContent).then(
      function(canShow) {
        if (canShow) {
          return MessageDialog.show(tmp.state.shareLinkContent);
        }
      }
    ).then(
      function(result) {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
          console.log('Share cancelled');
        } else {
          console.log('Share success with postId: '
            + result.postId);
        }
      },
      function(error) {
        console.log('Share fail with error: ' + error);
      }
    );
  }
```